# Three.js check ray intersection with an object by id

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to check if a ray intersects an object by the order in which it was added to the scene

```
 intersects = point.intersectObjects( scene.children );
```

Comment: Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the intersects property always returns objects in order of proximity.
however, you can give objects a name when adding them to the scene. when intersects returns them you can then order them by name.

example:
when adding to the scene set the name of an object as an int from a counter variable.

after you get the intersect array you can use array.sort() on it.

note, this only works if the objects are in their own group/object3d. since meshes cant have names.